# extract string between second and third occurrence of a slash

Tags: linux

I have a path string "/app/dev/xyz/tools"
how do i extract the word "dev" from the path string . (i am looking to extract a substring which is in between second and third occurrence  of a slash)

Answer (score 5):

With `cut` (`man cut`).

```
echo "/app/dev/xyz/tools" | \
  cut -d/ -f3
```

Comment: That assumes the pathname contains at least 3 /-delimited fields and no newline characters (and because of `echo`, that it doesn't contain backslash characters or is not `-n`,`-Enene` or whatever combination of options your `echo` implementation supports).

Answer (score 2):

With the `zsh` shell:

```
$ string=/app/dev/xyz/tools
$ third_component=${string:h3:t}
$ print -r - $third_component
dev
```

Like in `csh`, or `vim` (or `bash` but only for history expansion), the `:h` and `:t` modifiers return the *head* and *tail* respectively of a path.

`zsh` extended them to allow a number after them which specifies how much (how many components) of the *head* or *tail* to select, sp `${string:h3:t}` gives you the *tail* of the the 3-component *head* of the path stored in `$string`.

If `$string` contains fewer  than 3 components, that will return the last.

Actually, technically, that retrieves the 3<sup>rd</sup> path component, not necessarily the 3<sup>rd</sup> `/`-delimited field. For instance, in `a//b/c/d`, it gives you `c` not `b`. For the 3<sup>rd</sup> `/`-delimited field, you could use:

```
$ string=a//b/c/d
$ () { third_field=$3; } "${(@s[/])string}"
$ third_component=${string:h3:t}
$ print -r - $third_field $third_component
b c
```

You can do the same in POSIX shells using the split+glob operator:

```
$ string=a//b/c/d
$ set -o noglob
$ IFS=/
$ set -- $string""
$ third_field=$3
$ printf '%s\n' "$third_field"
b
```

Answer (score 2):

`echo "/app/dev/xyz/tools" | awk -F/ '{print $3}'`

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` (and other modern Bourne-like shells which support arrays), you can split the string into an array with just `echo` or `printf` (and [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution)) if you set the IFS variable appropriately.  e.g.

```
$ str="/app/dev/xyz/tools" 
$ OLDIFS="$IFS"; IFS=/; array=( $(echo "$str") ); IFS="$OLDIFS"
$ declare -p array
declare -a array=([0]="" [1]="app" [2]="dev" [3]="xyz" [4]="tools")
$ echo "${array[2]}"
dev
```

Note that bash array indices start from zero, not one. In this case, the zeroth element is empty because there's nothing before the first `/` in `$str`.

If you only need one of the path elements of the string, you're probably better off just using `cut` or `awk` to extract it.   If you need to iterate over each of the path elements, then having them in an array is convenient.